# Нет эффекта от ApplicationIntent в строке подключения

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, ado.net

В приложении, работающем на EF 6.1.3 (Code-First), генерируются отчеты Excel. Заранее невозможно сказать какой отчет понадобится в конкретном случае и поэтому пользователю разрешено генерировать отчеты на основе своего SQL запроса. Каким образом можно ограничить SQL запросы только на чтение?

На данный момент создаю строку подключения с ApplicationIntent.ReadOnly, но никакого эффекта это не даёт:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> ExecuteSqlQuery(string query) {
    string connStr = "...;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr)) {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            if(cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
            }
            using (var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                while (dataReader.Read()) {
                    var dataRow = GetDataRow(dataReader);
                    yield return dataRow;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Remove record in DB
ExecuteSqlQuery("DELETE FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE [dbo].[Col].[Id] = 1");
```

Может быть имеется другой способ добиться желаемого? Имеет ли смысл подставлять SELECT в начале запроса, а пользователю разрешить добавлять следующие за SELECT строки? Почему не работает ApplicationIntent?

Comment: Если не коммитить транзакцию, то в БД ничего не изменится, не так ли? Отправляйте команду в транзакции и затем откатывайте ее

Comment: @Андрей не могли бы Вы оформить это как ответ с примером кода?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему не работает [ApplicationIntent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover#ReadOnlyAppIntent) я так и не разобрался, но нашел способ, как мне кажется жизнеспособный, для того, чтоб определять используемые SQL выражения. Вполне возможно не вижу каких-либо подводных камней, а посему буду премного благодарен за полезные комментарии.

Существует возможность произвести синтаксический анализ SQL выражения с помощью [TSqlParser'а](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser.aspx) (я использовал [TSql120Parser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsql120parser.aspx) и поэтому не могу гарантировать работоспособность кода в других версиях). Необходимую библиотеку можно установить из [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom/). Принцип такой:

1. Пробуем получить список всех опознанных SQL выражений;
2. Проверяем наличие синтаксических ошибок;
3. Проверяем наличие полученных выражений либо в белом, либо в черном списке (ниже пример с белым списком);

```cs
using Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom;

public static bool CheckSqlExpressions(
                       string sql, 
                       List<string> whiteList, 
                       out IList<ParseError> errors
                   ) {

    var parser = new TSql120Parser(false);
    using (var reader = new StringReader(sql + ";")) {

        StatementList statementList = 
                      parser.ParseStatementList(reader, out errors);

        if (errors.Count > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (statementList == null) {
            return true;
        }

        foreach (var statement in statementList.Statements) {

            var typeName = statement.GetType().Name;
            if (whiteList.Contains(typeName) == false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Usage example:

string sql = "DELETE FROM TableName WHERE id = 1; COMMIT;";

// or use enumeration of all classes instead string
// https://gist.github.com/XelaNimed/d79afbe7f4b03878fdbd1924aad2455d
var whiteList = new List<string>(){
    "UseStatement",
    "SelectStatement",
    "SelectStatementSnippet"
};

bool res = CheckSqlExpressions(
               sql, 
               whiteList, 
               out IList<ParseError> parseErrors
           );
```

Ссылки:

- [TSqlParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser.aspx)
- [TSqlStatement Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlstatement.aspx)
- [SqlStatement Enumeration](https://gist.github.com/XelaNimed/d79afbe7f4b03878fdbd1924aad2455d)
- [ParseError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.parseerror.aspx)
- [Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom/)

Answer (score 5):

Если тебе необходимо ограничить права пользователя, работающего с SQL-сервером, используй для этого механизмы SQL-сервера. Создай нового пользователя с ролями `public` и `db_datareader`. Он сможет только читать, и не сможет модифицировать записи.

Comment: Дело в том, что пользователь сам создает подключения к БД и имеет к ней полный доступ. Мне же необходимо исключить возможность изменения данных из приложения вне зависимости от прав пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

У меня под рукой `Oracle`, поэтому покажу на ней, но для других БД код не будет отличаться:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var csb = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        DataSource = "...",
        UserID = "...",
        Password = "..."
    };
    using (var connection = new OracleConnection(csb.ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(); // Стартуем транзакцию
        var command = new OracleCommand("insert into ...", connection); // "Вредящая" команда
        command.Transaction = transaction; // Помещаем команду в созданную транзакцию
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) // Запускаем команду
        {
            ...
        }
        transaction.Rollback(); // Откатываем транзакцию
        // Если ее не закоммитить явно: transaction.Commit(),
        //  то она по умолчанию будет тоже откачена
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: идея хорошая, но достаточно дописать `;COMMIT` в текст команды - и транзакция закоммитается. и при этом rollback не упадет с исключением.

Comment: @PashaPash, вы правы, можно, конечно, искать в строке команды вхождение `commit`, но это не выход, всего не предусмотреть. Поэтому наиболее правильное решение - как указано в соседнем ответе, создать пользователя с ограниченными правами и запускать опасные команды под его именем